# Exchange Online: Incorrect recipient address after SMTP transfer

Tags: exchange

I have a user who originally had a user account named Bob. This account had a primary SMTP address of `bob.swanson@company.com` before any changes were made to it. Now, it turns out that Bob can no longer make use of this account, however, he still needs an account.

The new account should seamlessly function as it did before, which meant that the primary SMTP address had to be removed from the old account and provided for the new one. This leaves me with two user accounts for the same user:

Name: Bob Swanson (old)
SMTP: `bob.swansonold@company.com`
Auto-forward: `bob.swanson@company.com`
State: Disabled/Unused

Name: Bob Swanson
SMTP: `bob.swanson@company.com`
State: Enabled/Active

This works just fine most of the time, and almost every email received by the user is indeed addressed to `bob.swanson@company.com`, as was intended. Although, once every blue moon, the user receives an email addressed to `bob.swansonold@company.com` in his new inbox.

This is where my question begins: What exactly may be the cause for this incorrect display of information?

We know that the email does get delivered to the new inbox, no matter which of the two addresses you use (email forwarding is in effect). Yet, sometimes an email will display the old SMTP address in the recipient field.

I suspect that this may have to do with the X500 addresses of the old account being left untouched (Does the address book in Outlook make use of these?). Because, I highly doubt that a user would go out of their way in order to manually type `bob.swansonold@company.com` in the recipient field.

Thank you kindly for reading,
Mihkel

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you delete the old account in O365?
Do you mean to see the recipient on Bob's side? I suspect this issue may be caused by autocompleted. You could clear the cache and test again. Besides, could you reproduce this issue on OWA?